# Export data into excel

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to export data from datatable into excel file

I got this error

```
'EmployeeMaster$' is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that is not too long.
```

Here is my code

```
    Response.Clear()
    Dim dt_excel As New System.Data.DataTable
    Dim attach As String = "attachment; filename=EmployeeMaster.xls"

    File.Delete("C:\Users\Julian\Downloads\EmployeeMaster.xls")

    conn.connect()
    conn.connectExcel()
    dt_excel = conn.openReader("Select * from EmployeeMaster")

    Response.ClearContent()
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attach)
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"

    Dim tab As String = ""
    For Each dc As DataColumn In dt_excel.Columns
        Response.Write(tab + dc.ColumnName)
        tab = vbTab
    Next
    Response.Write(vbLf)

    conn.openReaderExcel("Create Table [EmployeeMaster$] (EmployeeNo varchar(25))") '<- throw error here
    For Each dr As DataRow In dt_excel.Rows
        tab = ""
        conn.openReaderExcel("Insert into [EmployeeMaster$] (EmployeeNo) values ('" & dr.Item("EmployeeNo") & "')")
        Response.Write(vbLf)
    Next
    Response.End()
```

I keep wondering what is wrong with my code..could anyone suggest me the way to solve this problem??

all suggestion/help will be appreciated

Regards Siekh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a bit late to answer, but I think the problem here resides in the use of `[` and `]` characters in the "table" (=sheet) name... while it's OK in most databases, you're dealing with excel here...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Protected Sub btnExportExcel_Click(ByVal sender As Object,
ByVal e As EventArgs)
Response.Clear()
Response.Buffer = True

Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
"attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls")
Response.Charset = ""
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"

Dim sw As New StringWriter()
Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)

GridView1.AllowPaging = False
GridView1.DataBind()

'Change the Header Row back to white color
GridView1.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#FFFFFF")

'Apply style to Individual Cells
GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(0).Style.Add("background-color", "green")
GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(1).Style.Add("background-color", "green")
GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(2).Style.Add("background-color", "green")
GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(3).Style.Add("background-color", "green")

For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
 Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView1.Rows(i)

 'Change Color back to white
 row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White

'Apply text style to each Row
row.Attributes.Add("class", "textmode")

'Apply style to Individual Cells of Alternating Row
 If i Mod 2 <> 0 Then
  row.Cells(0).Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B")
 row.Cells(1).Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B")
 row.Cells(2).Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B")
 row.Cells(3).Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B")
  End If
 Next
GridView1.RenderControl(hw)

'style to format numbers to string
Dim style As String = "<style>.textmode{mso-number-format:\@;}</style>"
Response.Write(style)
Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString())
Response.Flush()
Response.End()
End Sub
```

[**Reference Link**](http://archive.aspsnippets.com/post/2009/03/14/Export-GridView-To-WordExcelPDFCSV-in-ASPNet.aspx)

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks but I don't think it will solve my problem..my problem locate on create table query hehehe

Comment: Have you tried post. what do mean by `hehehe`.Someone gives you answer and did not take seriously.

Comment: what I mean with that was smiling

Comment: This doesn't actually export and excel file, but an HTML file with xls extension. Although the illusion is almost perfect, Excel will display a warning message upon opening. In addition, if an import is needed it may be trickier to access the data.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to use Datasets?? because u can create custom queries in there...no need for all the code...and then assign this query to a datatable or even a datagrid then export it to excel. If u use datasets,datatables/datagridviews and need the code letme know